# Why "add one smoothing" in language model does not count the </s> in denominator

Tags: nlp, language-model

English is not my native language , Sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

I saw many documents for add one smoothing in language model, and I still very confused about the variable V in the formula:

```
P (wi |w_i-1 ) = c(w_i-1 ,wi )+1  / c(w_i-1 )+V
```

as for this example corpus and I use bigram

```
<s> John read Moby Dick </s>
<s> Mary read a different book </s>
<s> She read a book by Cher </s>
```

if i want to calculate any P(wi | w_i-1) . The V will be 11
because the count of combination of [ w_i-1 , w ] is 11
. But I found it does not include the case   [w_i-1 , "<"/s">"]  (or the V will be 12)
Why we do not need to include this case ? Isn't it the case that w_i-1 is in the end of an article or sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice tutorial here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/~wcmac/papers/20050421-smoothing-tutorial.pdf

Consider an ngram language model (without smoothing):

> p(w_i | w_i-1) = c(w_i-1 w_i) / c(w_i-1)
>
> p(w_1, w_2 ... w_n) = product_i=1_to_n( p(w_i | w_i-1) )

In code:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import mul

from nltk import ngrams

def prob_product(prob_list):
    return reduce(mul, prob_list, 1)

text = [['<s>', 'John', 'read', 'Moby', 'Dick', '</s>'], 
        ['<s>', 'Mary', 'read', 'a', 'different', 'book', '</s>'], 
        ['<s>', 'She', 'read', 'a', 'book', 'by', 'Cher', '</s>']]

bigram_counts = sum([Counter(ngrams(t, 2)) for t in text], Counter())
unigram_counts = sum([Counter(ngrams(t, 1)) for t in text], Counter())

count_S_John = bigram_counts[('<s>', 'John')]
count_S = unigram_counts[('<s>',)]

sentence = '<s> John read a book </s>'.split()
prob_S_John_read_a_book = prob_product([bigram_counts[bg]/unigram_counts[bg[:-1]]
                                        for bg in ngrams(sentence, 2)])

print(prob_S_John_read_a_book) # 0.555555

for bg in ngrams(sentence, 2):
    print(bg, bigram_counts[bg], unigram_counts[bg[:-1]])
```

[out]:

```
0.55555
('<s>', 'John') 1 3
('John', 'read') 1 1
('read', 'a') 2 3
('a', 'book') 1 2
('book', '</s>') 1 2
```

With add-one smoothing, aka [Laplace smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing),

> p(w_i | w_i-1) = (1 + c(w_i-1 w_i)) / (|V| + c(w_i-1))

where `|V|` is the number of tokens (usually without `<s>` and `</s>`).

So in code:

```
laplace_prob_S_John_read_a_book = prob_product([(1+bigram_counts[bg]) / (len(unigram_counts)-2 + unigram_counts[bg[:-1]])
                                                for bg in ngrams(sentence, 2)])

print(laplace_prob_S_John_read_a_book)

for bg in ngrams(sentence, 2):
    print(bg, 1+bigram_counts[bg], len(unigram_counts)-2 + unigram_counts[bg[:-1]])
```

[out]:

```
0.00012075836251660427
('<s>', 'John') 2 14
('John', 'read') 2 12
('read', 'a') 3 14
('a', 'book') 2 13
('book', '</s>') 2 13
```

Note: `len(unigram_counts)-2` accounts for removing `<s>` and `</s>` from the no. of words in vocabulary.

---

The above it the how.

**Q: Why doesn't the `|V|` takes into account `<s>` and `</s>`?**

**A:** One possible reason is because we never consider empty sentences in language models, so the `<s>` and `</s>` can't stand by itself and the vocabulary `|V|` excludes them.

**Is it okay to add them in `|V|`?**

**A:** Actually if `|V|` is *sufficiently large*, having +2 for `<s>` and `</s>` would make little difference. As long as `|V|` is consistent and fixed consistent in all the computation and it's *sufficiently large*, the language model probabilities of any sentence relative to another sentence with the same language model shouldn't be too different.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I want to ask , for example in the p.8 of the tutorial . When we want to calculate p(READ|CHER) , we also take [CHER , </S>] into account, so the denominator is 1 . But why we don't take it into account when we consider the add one smoothing ?